# Delete Duplicate records with exact value

Tags: mysql, duplicates

How to delete duplicate records when both rows the exact same records?

```
create table item
(id int,
product_name varchar(20),
quantity int,
amount decimal(10,2)
);

insert into item values(1,"Laptop",10,89.9),(1,"Laptop",10,89.9),(2,"Mixer",8,82),(4,"Fridge",9,100);
```

This is deleting all the records for duplicate id

```
DELETE FROM item
WHERE ID IN (SELECT id,row_num FROM (SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS row_num FROM item) t
WHERE row_num > 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would actually suggest creating a temporary table, inserting the records sans duplicates, then renaming the temp table to the original table name.

```sql
CREATE TABLE item2 (
    id int,
    product_name varchar(20),
    quantity int,
    amount decimal(10,2)
);

INSERT INTO item2 (id, product_name, quantity, amount)
SELECT DISTINCT id, product_name, quantity, amount
FROM item;

DROP TABLE item;
ALTER TABLE item2 RENAME TO item;
DROP TABLE item2;
```

Comment: So the approach is this only, there is nothing I can do within the delete statement? I tried the temporary table one, it worked thanks!

Comment: @SHIKHASINGH While there might be a way to tease out an answer using `DELETE`, it is challenging because the duplicate records, one of which you want to remove, are completely identical.  Most delete would rely on some column(s) to figure out which one to retain.  This is not possible with your data.

Answer (score 0):

Create a duplicate table with a new primary key or unique key
then get all the duplicate records
select id from item  where id =1 HAVING COUNT(*)>1
will get you all the duplicate records with new primary key or unique key

copy the primary key which you want to delete

delete from item where id IN (1,2,3,5..............)